# Why do I not get a backtrace when my program has a segmentation fault even though RUST_BACKTRACE=1 is set?

Tags: rust, segmentation-fault

I want to see the backtrace of a random segmentation fault, so I set the `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable. Normally it prints the backtrace info, but this time it doesn't. Why doesn't `RUST_BACKTRACE` work?

```
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 ./target/debug/grin-miner
...
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have tried multiple times and always get no backtraces. If the error is in external libraries, will `RUST_BACKTRACE` do the job or not?

Comment: "If the error is in the external libraries, RUST_BACKTRACE will do the job or not?", I don't think, rust will show you the backtrace when it's panic, but a segfault will stop your program. try `vagrind ./target/debug/grin-miner`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`RUST_BACKTRACE` only prints out a backtrace for Rust-generated panics. A segfault is a lower-level failure than a panic. You will need to use a debugger (GDB, LLDB, WinDbg, etc.) to investigate the failure.

Comment: Thanks Shepmaster. I switch to lldb and get the backtraces.  `$ rust-lldb ./target/debug/grin-miner` and then when `Segmentation fault` happen, input `thread backtrace`