# Rust program using CPython FFI silently getting killed

Tags: rust, ffi, cpython

I have a Rust program which is exiting silently without any trace of the reason in the logs. This would happen after several successful calls to the same method. The last log I see is one after which a FFI call is made. I do not get a log after the return of the FFI call.

```
use cpython;
use cpython::ObjectProtocol;
use cpython::PyResult;
```

```
fn is_complete(&self, check: bool) -> Result<bool, PyModuleError> {
    let gil = cpython::Python::acquire_gil();
    let py = gil.python();
    debug!("Calling complete"); //This is the last log
    let res = self
        .py_complete
        .call_method(py, "complete", (check,), None)
        .expect("No method complete on python module")
        .extract::<bool>(py).unwrap();
    if res {
        debug!("Returning true"); //This does not appear
        Ok(true)                
    }
    else {
        debug!("Returning false"); //This does not appear
        Ok(false)
    }
}
```

The Python module does return a value as I had debug logs there as well to confirm.

I have tried using `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` but in vain.

Comment: [Why do I not get a backtrace when my program has a segmentation fault even though RUST_BACKTRACE=1 is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50458782/155423) — Run in a debugger.

Comment: Thanks @Shepmaster for pointing me out to this post. I do not get any coredumps either. Will try and run GDB.

Comment: There are many reasons a coredump may not be written. This may also just be a call to [`std::process::exit`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/fn.exit.html) or an explicit abort somewhere in (poorly written?) code.